# VSCode tasks.,json file cannot be excluded

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have next tasks.json

```
"inputs": [
    {
      "id": "pickBuild",
      "type": "command",
      "command": "extension.commandvariable.transform",
      "args": {
        "text": "${pickFile:build}",
        "find": ".*(default_.*).py",
        "replace": "$1",
        "pickFile": {
          "build": {
            "include": "**/default_*.py",
            "exclude": "**/{default_keyboard_*.py, default_mouse_*.py}",
            "description": "Select build",
            "display": "fileName",
          }
        }
      }
    }
]
```

eventhough default_mouse_*.py excluded, I still can see it in options

expected: default_keyboard_*.py and default_mouse_*.py should be excluded

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Should no space inside the brackets.

what I had:

```
"exclude": "**/{default_keyboard_\*.py, default_mouse_\*.py}"
```

solution:

```
"exclude": "**/default_{keyboard_\*,mouse_\*}"
```